# Confused with the sound of b in one word

Tags: pronunciation

Usually the **b** does not pose problems for me understanding Italian. But recently twice I have heard while watching some old movies the word **baldracca**, and the b sounded both times for me like **v**. Is this word an exception, or it's me not hearing properly?

**UPDATE**
Thank you guys for answering my question. I have upped the volume considerably
and now I hear the propper **b**
The movie where I heard first the word was **I Marziani Hanno 12 Mani 1964**,
and the word is pronounced on 1:18:17 and again a second later.

Comment: I'm not aware of regional varieties of Italian where /b/ is pronounced like [v] (or similar sounds) like in Spanish. On the other hand, our perception of foreign languages often merges unusual heard sounds with ones of our main language.

Comment: One or more specific examples would be quite useful.

Comment: @Charo, thank you for the link to the dictionary i was unaware of.

Comment: Since we're here... In Italian only the first word of a title (an proper nouns, if any) is written with a capital letter. So, it's _I marziani hanno 12 mani_.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because apparently it's not asking anything anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "baldracca" isn't an exception. As you can see, according to [Dizionario d’ortografia e di pronunzia](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=76992&r=3965), its ***b*** it's pronounced [b].